# Is there a way to represent an object of key-value pairs in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, key-value, graphql, key-value-store, graphql-js

I am using GraphQL in my Node.js application. And I want to store an object that uses keys as a locale short code and values for the string in the corresponding language. (like `{ en: "Hello", ru: "Привет" }` etc.)

I want to represent this using GraphQL, both in input (like that):

```
mutation {
  addExercise(name: { en: "Hello", ru: "Привет" })
}
```

and in output (like that)

```
{
  exercises {
    _id, name
  }
}
```

(`name` should return an object of key-value pairs:)

```
[
  {_id: 1, name: { en: "Hello", ru: "Привет" }}
]
```

How can I do something like that?

I know I can store my data this way

```
{ name: "en", value: "Hello }`
```

but the previous one seems to be easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can define scalar type for JSON, and then return the data as is.
here is an example library that does just that (use it or copy & modify):
https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json/blob/master/src/index.js

enjoy!